# Consumer doesn't work in my simple producer/consumer/queue code in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, polling, producer-consumer

I am trying to implement a simple producer/consumer system in Java 11. Basically, I take two threads for each, plus a global queue, simply as follows:

- A global priority queue.
- The first thread, producer, runs a HTTP server, listens to incoming http messages, and upon receiving a message, `pushes` it as a job to the queue (`queue.size` increments)
- The second thread, the consumer, continously `peeks` the queue. If there is a job (`job ! = null`), submits a HTTP request somewhere and upon successful receipt, polls it from the queue (`queue.size()` decrements).

The skeleton is as below:

Main Class:

```
public class Manager
{
    private Consumer consumer;
    private Producer producer;
    Queue queue;

    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        consumer = new Consumer();
        producer = new Producer();
    }
}
```

Producer class:

```
public class Producer implements Runnable
{
    public Producer()
    {
        Thread producer = new Thread(this);
        producer.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
            //HTTP server starts, listens, and adds to the queue upon receiving a Job
            server.start();
            Manager.queue.add(new Job());
    }
}
```

Consumer class:

```
public class Consumer implements Runnable
{
    public Consumer()
    {
        Thread consumer = new Thread(this);
        consumer.start();
    }

    public void run()
    {
    // Thread.sleep(1);

        while(true)
        {
            //get an object off the queue
            Job job= Manager.queue.peek();
            //do some stuff with the object
        }
    }
}
```

`Producer` and `queue` works- all good. But the problem is with the `Consumer`. The Consumer code above (with `while(true)` loop) doesn't peek the item. But when I add a `Thread.sleep(x)` before `while(true)` loop, even if `x=1 ms`, it works, and grabs the item successfully.

What is the problem? Theoretically, `while(true)` loop shouldn't be a problem! Why it can not see and `peek` the item?!

Comment: What are you initializing `queue` with?

Comment: Queue is empty initially. Just with a size of 2000.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not help me. What class are you using to initialize `queue`? Can you post the full code?

Comment: `static PriorityQueue<Job> jobSubmissionQueue`

Comment: Full code is very large!

Comment: `PriorityQueue` is not thread-safe. You can use `PriorityBlockingQueue` in place of it, which *is* thread-safe.

Comment: Heh interesting! That simple type change now works! Is it due to the same reason Poohi mentioned? (local copy is not kept anymore).

Comment: Yes, but the synchronization in `PriorityBlockingQueue` is handled for you so you don't need to synchronize anything (related to the queue) yourself. I've posted my own answer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem: non-synchronized reading and writing from and to a queue.

What happens here is that both threads, running on different CPU-cores work with their own copy of the queue, thus the producer might be adding stuff and these changes probably even get propagated into RAM, but the consumer never checks for anything in RAM, since it has it's own cached copy of that queue, witch stays empty.

The `Thread.sleep()` thing works, because when waking up, the thread has to get all ist stuff from RAM, where it probably changed.

The correct way of doing it, is only accessing the Queue, when synchronized on it as follows:

In producer:

```
synchronized(Manager.queue) {
     Manager.queue.add(new Job());
}
```

and in Consumer:

```
boolean continue = true;
while (continue) {
    synchronized(Manager.queue) {
        Job job=Manager.queue.pop();
    }
}
```

And as a final touch: the `while (true)`-thing is incredibly inefficient, you could do something using `Object.wait()` and `Object.notify()`

In producer:

```
synchronized(Manager.queue) {
     Manager.queue.add(new Job());
     Manager.queue.notify();
}
```

and in Consumer:

```
boolean continue = true;
while (continue) {
    synchronized(Manager.queue) {
        while (Manager.queue.peek() == null) {
            Manager.queue.wait();
        }
        Job job=Manager.queue.pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: How much overhead does `while(true)` really add? Is it super bad?!

Comment: Yes, it pinns one cpu-core at 100%, causing your system to effectively lose a CPU-core and forces the cpu to run at full speed, causing unnecesarry power consumption and heat. If you don't want to deal with `Object.notify()` at least do `Thread.sleep(10)`, to let the cpu idle most he time.

Comment: I have a problem here. The second `poll` never works. Only the first one works. I'm trying to print something inside your while loop, but `while (Manager.queue.peek() == null) {     System.out.println("111111111111111");` doesn't print anything for second poll. How to fix it?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `poll`. If your wondering why the `while` loop never loops, thats because the `notify()` and `wait()` logic should prevent this, you could in theory use an `if` if you really wanted to, but this `while` loop catches any coding errors and spontaneous wakeups that could interfere. Don't use `if`. If by `poll` you mean `pop`: maybe the new `Job` was added before the consumer looked for a new one, so no waiting was ever done and the `while` loop never executed even once.

Comment: Yes, looks like somewhere the logic is failing. Consumer is in loop, prints("1111"), waits. Same time, Producer adds, notifies. Consumer pops. Again producer adds, notifies. But consumer doesn't go to loop to print 1111 for the second time. Why?!

Comment: Because the condition in the `while` tells it that there already is an element ready to be `pop`ed, so there is no need to wait (so no need to enter the loop). And note: nothing here is happening "at the same time", the main purpose of synchronized is to prevent this. What is actually happening in your example is `peek() -> wait() -> add() -> peek() -> pop() -> add() -> peek() -> pop()`

Comment: My new question just asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53823767/producer-consumer-code-with-wait-notify-doesnt-work-on-second-produce

Comment: @Poohi please update your answer to keep that `while(true)` wrap around what you the `synchronized` block. I thought the `while(true)` loop must be removed.

Comment: Ow, you mean _that_ `while(true)`, I am sorry, I thought you were talking about a dedicated `while(true)` that did `while (peek() == null) {}`. I'm so sorry for the hassle.

Answer (score 1):

`PriorityQueue` is **not** thread-safe whereas `PriorityBlockingQueue` **is**. As long as you aren't using any methods defined in the `BlockingQueue` interface, these two implementations are interchangeable.  Simply changing `PriorityQueue` to `PriorityBlockingQueue` should fix your problem.

Comment: How much overhead does `while(true)` really add? Is it super bad?!